# Windows RDS - speed up log-off

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, logoff

It takes 20-30 seconds for the logoff procedure to complete on our 2012R2 RDS server.  This causes issues for our RemoteApp users.  I'm curious if anyone out there has thoughts on how to speed up logoffs, or possible profile the logoff procedure so that I can try to determine what's hanging it up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using roaming profiles? If so, how large are the profiles?

Comment: We use policy to disable roaming profiles on our RDS servers.

Comment: 1. You can use ProcMon to monitor the procedure (include events by session number, not by user name). 2. [Enable debuging](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-verbose-status-message-windows).

Comment: 1. I am unfamiliar with using Process Monitor to create a log of which processes are slow to terminate, causing a logoff operation to go slowly.  2. Verbose messages don't do anything for RemoteApps.  Our Remote Application, itself, exits quickly.  But it takes another 20-30 seconds for the other misc. processes to fully exit and close the user profile.

Comment: I'm curious how users even notice a slow logoff?  Presumably they've closed the app window because they're done with their session, right?  And they're either walking away or switching to a new non-RDS related task.  But the 20-30 seconds it takes for the session to fully close they shouldn't notice because that's only happening server side.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Our ERP application is not always well behaved, and some times the only "fix" for it is for a user to exit it _as well as their user session_.  However, if they don't wait a full 30 seconds, they may launch inside their previous, as-yet still open, user session, which retains whatever problems the ERP application was having.  Their problems remain.  And then they call me.  And it simply does not matter how many times this happens or how I explain it, some people simply repeat their past failures again and again.  So, I'm looking to speed up the logoff to retain my sanity.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed "Microsoft Baseline Security Analyzer" in your Windows server 2012 server?

Microsoft Baseline Security Analyzer can cause significant slow log off. Here is the reference.

http://www.networksteve.com/forum/topic.php/Extremely_slow_RDP_session_-_Solved/?TopicId=39213&Posts=1

Hope that helps
Thanks,

Comment: I double-checked just to make sure a contractor hadn't added it -- no, MBSA is not installed, and FIPS signing is disabled.  Thanks for the idea though. It was worth checking.